# Cant find CopyTo in googlesheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

im trying to copy values from specified cells in sheet1 to specified cells in  sheet2 via button on click and this is my code

```
  function CopyPaste() {
    var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');            
    var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');   
    sheet1.getRange('G2').getValue().copyTo(sheet2.getRange('A45')) ;
  //sheet1.getRange('I2').getValue().copyTo(sheet2.getRange('B45')) ;
  //sheet1.getRange('K2').getValue().copyTo(sheet2.getRange('C45')) ;
}
```

Actually im trying to copy 3 at once but for now i want just see why its not working . im getting this error

```
    TypeError: Can not find function in object copyTo
```

any help pls?

INFO : my G2 has calculated value . I man there is formula in that cell and want get only value not the formula .

**EDIT** if its possible to copy those 3 values in same time it will be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getValues()` just returns a 2d array.
`copyTo` works on range objects and can handle those is customizable ways through the optional `options` parameter.

```
function CopyPaste() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');            
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');   
  sheet1.getRange('G2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('A45')) ;
  // sheet1.getRange('I2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('B45')) ;
  // sheet1.getRange('K2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('C45')) ;
}
```

If you want only the values, not the formula generating it you need to supply the options parameter:

```
sheet1.getRange('G2').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('A45'), {contentsOnly: true});
```

Alterantively at this point you can rewrite the function:

```
function CopyPaste() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');            
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');   

sheet2.getRange("A45:C45").setValues([[
  sheet1.getRange('G2').getValue(),
  sheet1.getRange('I2').getValue(),
  sheet1.getRange('K2').getValue()]])
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer doing what you said im getting the formula value in B45 sheet2 with error message `Circular dependency detected.` . i want the value only .

Comment: and can copy all those 3 values at the samne time ?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Since the three source cells are not adjacent you need to get their values separately (or get the whole range and remove what's in between which is more opaque.

Comment: hahaha i laugh because it runs wonderfully :) , you are awsome :) . i lost 1 day searching on this issue tills i decided to write my problem here :) . thanks a lot genius :) .

Comment: Ohhh sorry one quick question pls . what if i have many buttons in many rows , so i have to pull the values programatically not those speciefied G2 I2  K2 ?? I mean the row values where the button was clicked in that row . so if the button is in row 4 i want to get G4  I4 K4  ??

Comment: Buttons aren't really assigned to rows so you'd have to create a wrapper for every row and assign it to the corresponding button. I would instead of the buttons do a data validation drop down, when you set it to true it triggers the function [on edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) which can read the row from the e parameter. The last thing the function would do is reset the drop down to blank or false.

Comment: Ok and how do i change this function to forexample Gi , Ii Ki i mean not specified row . only when i trigger the speciefied row . because G2 I2 K2 is just for row 2

Comment: The [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) has a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) part from which you can get the row. You can then generate the range through string concatenation.

Comment: I dont know how i can do that maybe i will open new question , since you explained but i didnt understnd how to apply it and do it . can you edit your question and add your solution ?

Comment: My comments have links in them to the documentation which also has examples. Try checking those out. Creating an onedit function is as simple as calling the function onEdit.

Comment: I guess its little difficult for me , maybe i will do 200 functions with every function has a name ex CopyPaste1()  CopyPaste2() CopyPaste3()  and put every function in the button of that row .

Comment: Sorry for disturbing :) , i think i got an idea . what if for example i have function assigned to every button in every row like that : `CopyPaste(1)` , `CopyPaste(2)` .... so on which 1 and 2 are the number of row . and then in the function we use those row numbers to trigger just that row from this number ? have you some work around this pls ? and my main functions will be `CopyPaste(i)`  some suggestion :) and work around this ?

Comment: If you want to do it this way you have to create a function `row1function(){copyPaste(1);}` and so on and copypaste concatenates the string `getRange("A"+row)`. I still recommend reading the reference links I posted and doing it with data validation and onedit triggers

Comment: thanks . sorry im not good in that scripting in google sheet , so thanks i will do what u said now in your last comment